# How to add post tags to WooCommerce products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I noticed that post tags are different than WooCommerce product tags.

I need to add post tags to WooCommerce products so i can include some WooCommerce products in the post tag archives.

Is this possible?

I've tried these code snippets but it doesn't add them.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_types' );

function add_custom_types( $query ) {

  if ( is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {

    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'products', 'product' ) );
      return $query;
    }
}

add_filter('request', 'post_type_tags_fix');

function post_type_tags_fix($request) {
    if ( isset($request['tag']) && !isset($request['post_type']) )
    $request['post_type'] = array( 'products', 'product' );
    return $request;
}
```

Comment: @Dav product tags is same as post tags. Can you tell me why you need new tags?

Comment: Post tags are NOT the same as product tags and use different tag archive pages. I want to tag some products so they are included in the post tag archives for a blog page.

Comment: Check my answer. you need to add filter in your theme functions.php file

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this as well and have come up with what I think is a good way of doing this. A few steps:

Firstly, you need to add the post_tag taxonomy to the woocommerce product post type. You can do this easily with the following filter:

```
function custom_wc_add_post_tags( $args ){
   $args['taxonomies'] =  array('post_tag');
   return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'custom_wc_add_post_tags' );
```

This will add a new 'Tags' item to your admin menu, and allow you to tag products with regular post tags rather that the woocommerce-specific 'product_tag' taxonomy. Secondly, you'll likely want to remove the 'product_tag' taxonomy if you don't plan on using it? Because the above will result in two admin menu items called 'tags' which will get confusing. The following will do that for you:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_product_tag', '__return_empty_array');
add_filter('woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_tag', '__return_empty_array');
```

And to remove the column from the 'Products' table on the backend:

```
function custom_wc_remove_product_tags_column($columns){
   unset( $columns['product_tag'] );
   return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'custom_wc_remove_product_tags_column', 15 );
```

That will actually add the tags to your products. If you then need these  to show up in your archive page, you may still need to modify that page's query to look for posts of type 'product' as well as the standard 'post'. It looks like your function above on the 'pre_get_posts' hook will do that part for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried multiple different methods and this was the only one to do exactly what I want. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get archive page in product tag page. now product tag page use theme archive.php file.

Add Below code in theme **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'woocommerce_product_tag_page_template', 99 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'hcode_post_format_parameter' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_product_tag_page_template( $template ) {

        if ( is_tax( 'product_tag' ) ) {
            get_template_part('archive');
        }

        return $template;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't enable me to tag WooCommerce products using post tags so they are included in post tag archives.

Comment: @Dav post tags and product tags are both different as there post type so it work as separably

Comment: I need a solution that enables me to add products tagged with post tags to post tag archives, not WooCommerce product tag archives.

Comment: Both tags have different post type so it should work with different pages

Comment: @MukeshPanchal how do you know the list of woocommer's tags, I mean ('template_include') how can I know what tag I need, for example (before show all the information about a single product).

Comment: It's solution for woocomerce tag page means after adding above code in functions.php woocomerce tag take your theme archive.php page. You can change is as per your need